# How activity will come to know if loaders data is changed or modified?

Tags: android, android-activity, loader

I have implemented a loader and the data which I am getting in onLoadFinished() is passed to ViewPager's adapter.

Loader is perfectly getting updated when data source is changed but there is a scenario where I need to notice activity that data has been changed.

How activity will come to know if loaders data is changed ?

Comment: The Loader has a callback for that. As long as the data source is well behaved and correctly notifies clients about changes this should all work right out of the box.

Comment: @XaverKapeller when data source is modified , which loader method is called ?? onLoaderReset ??

Comment: You can use interface call back for this.